# how to calculate distance between two location in map(google map, mapbox )

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

i want to calculate distance as i want to to  use in react project. I don't how to approach for this but any hint or help will be useful to me .Thanks in advance

Comment: Driving distance or straight line distance?

Comment: driving distance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get the distance between two locations based on their latitude and longitude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46723333/how-to-get-the-distance-between-two-locations-based-on-their-latitude-and-longit)

Answer (score 0):

Use Google's distance matrix Api for this
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/overview